# DQL issue on where clause

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Hello i have this Clause:

```
SELECT y,
CASE WHEN (v IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(v.viewCount) END AS HIDDEN sumviewcount
FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y
LEFT JOIN y.allViews v WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
GROUP BY y ORDER BY sumviewcount DESC
```

Which works completly fine, but when i attempt to add a WHERE clause, like:

```
SELECT y,
CASE WHEN (v IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(v.viewCount) END AS HIDDEN sumviewcount
FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y
LEFT JOIN y.allViews v WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
WHERE y.name LIKE :videoName
GROUP BY y ORDER BY sumviewcount DESC
```

videoName is bound like this:

```
$query->setParameter('videoName', "%" . $searchData['searchValue'] . "%");
```

So that is not the issue, anyway the error i am getting is:

```
Error: Expected end of string, got 'y'","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException
```

Comment: Have you tried different values for the search value?

Comment: `HIDDEN sumviewcount` should be one word or wrap inside quotes i.e. `"HIDDEN sumviewcount"`